# Smartgit Integrate Develop not available - Bitbucket # commits behind | # commits ahead

Tags: git, bitbucket, commit, smartgit

I am using Smartgit and Bitbucket to commit my code. 
I did not check in code for many weeks and now I am so many commits behind. I am working from my own branch say branch x; not the Develop branch.
My problem is I need to get caught up on those many commits behind from Smartgit.
I am new to Smartgit and wondering: how do I get those commits I am behind on into my current branch so that I can merge conflicts locally and check in and be finally caught up?

```
    1. I tried Pull, Merge fetched remote changes NOT Rebase local 
       branch onto fetched changes

    2. I tried looking for 'Integrate Develop' by right clicking on 
       my Git-Flow feature branch and that 'Integrate Develop' option wasn't available
```

Does anyone have any idea how, from my feature branch, I would get the latest code from Bitbucket, using SMARTGIT so that I am no longer 200 commits behind and thereby having conflicts when going to check in my code?

PS. I am NOT using GIT command prompt; I'd prefer a solution that uses Smartgit but if you have an idea using the command prompt only, then that's fine as well, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the **Log** and make sure that your feature branch is HEAD (green arrow). Make sure that your remote `origin/develop` is visible (selected in the **Branches** view, you may use **Reveal** there). Finally, select `origin/develop` and from the context menu invoke **Rebase HEAD to**. Alternatively, if you prefer merging, select **Merge**.

Comment: Thanks mstrap for your response; I checked out current feature branch (green triangle) and selected 'origin/master', right clicked on it and did a Rebase Head To and it ran for a while then said 'rebased failed(return code1) Could not pick 1303839048j34j3l4343434 - these are just random hexadecimal I typed in to make it easier for me; doesn't actually match exactly to the hex in the error message.

Comment: Actually I think the reason that Rebase HEAD To operation failed is probably because my local code changes are conflicting with the server one. So I just need to 'discard' changes and keep retrying the Rebase Head To until there's no more conflicts and I think the local code will mirror exactly the remote one and I'll be caught up right; my understanding is correct mstrap?

Comment: That actually was the issue for anyone who runs into this problem although many developers don't wait till they're 200 commits behind. Keep discarding local changes on your feature branch, check out feature branch (green triangle) and right click on 'origin/master' and select 'Rebase Head To' until the rebase passes. The rebase operation will keep failing but looking into the Output (bottom right) of Smartgit, you'll notice that you're catching up i.e a number will rise to catch up to the # of commits you were behind something like Rebase (12 | 200) where 200 is the # of commits you're behind

Comment: You better shouldn't Discard changes, but Resolve them from the working tree window (e.g using the Conflict Solver). Sometimes resolving a change may actually mean to discard your modifications because they already became obsolete on master/develop.

"Rebase (12 | 200)" means that it's currently rebasing commit #12 of 200. Are you sure that your feature branch has 200 commits?

Comment: I solved this problem by merging the 'develop' branch (which was ahead by 200 commits) into my checked out feature branch, then I pushed my feature branch to server; this caught me up i.e my feature branch is no longer 200 commits behind develop. Thanks again mstrap, hope this helps someone else

Comment: But why does this happen ?  is this because we created the branch in github directly instead of smart git ?  . I see 'integrate develop' enabled for branches I created in smart git and pushed to origin but not the other way around .